# if return statement in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, return, overriding

I am overriding a virtual method and I need to return a value depending on a bool expression.

```
  public override float Q()
    {
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A* B / C);
    }
```

I need to return a local member (call it D) for Q() if the calculated value shown above is less than D. I tried using regular if statements, but it won't return a value unless it's returned outside the if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: So is the code above the base class or the derived class? Do you want the derived class to return the value from the base class

Answer (score 8):

How about skipping the `if` altogether:

```
return Math.Max(D, Math.Sqrt (2*A*B/C));
```

or with ternary operator

```
return  Math.Sqrt (2*A*B/C) < D ? D :  Math.Sqrt (2*A*B/C); // too verbose but you get the idea
```

Comment: I think you meant `Math.Max`.

Answer (score 0):

i would think this would work

```
public override float Q(){
    var returnValue = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A * B / C);

    if (returnValue < D){
        return D;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

**EDIT :** 
or you can clean it up to this

```
public override float Q(){
    var returnValue = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A * B / C);

    return returnValue < D ? D : returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public override float Q()
{
    var result = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A* B / C);
    return result < D ? D : result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a trick question, since `D` is local to the class, the code should look like this:

```
public override float Q()
{
    var result = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A* B / C);
    return result < D ? D : result;
}
```

but note that `D` needs to be a `float` or cast to a `float` on the return if it's not. Further, if `D` isn't a `float` you may want to just do something like this because its type may not be implicitly convertable:

```
public override float Q()
{
    var d = (float)D;
    var result = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A* B / C);
    return result < d ? d : result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public override float Q(){
    var r = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * A * B / C);

    if (r < D){
        r = D;
    }

    return r;
}
```